# Can I set Dark Mode dynamically on my iPhone like I can in macOS?

Tags: ios, wallpaper, dark-mode

I have a Mac with Mojave installed and I can set my desktop background to be Dynamic:

[image]

This means my desktop picture will change from a hot sunny desert picture to a cool dark night-time desert picture.

Is there a way for me to set the dark mode on my iPhone so that it does the same thing? I would like it to be bright during the day and dark at night.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have iOS 13 installed, follow these steps:

1. Go to **Settings**
2. Tap on **Display & Brightness**
3. Enable the **Automatic** option (it’s just below the Light and Dark images at top)
4. This will reveal the **Options** setting - tap on this
5. You can now choose between *Sunset to Sunrise* or setting a *Custom Schedule*
6. Selecting the:

   - **Sunset to Sunrise** setting will mimic what macOS does with its Dynamic Desktop (i.e. change from Light to Dark mode based on your location)
   - **Custom Schedule** setting means you can manually select the exact times you want it to change from Light to Dark and back again

**NOTE:**

Since you're also wanting your iPhone background image (or Wallpaper) to change dynamically, you will need to go to **Settings > Wallpaper** and toggle the *Dark Appearance Dims Wallpaper* option. This doesn't work in the same was as it does in macOS, but your Wallpaper's appearance will change somewhat whenever your iPhone changes from Light to Dark and back again

Comment: That's cool. Can I also get it to change the look of my background pic?

Comment: @Accountant I've just updated my answer with some extra info re your iPhone's wallpaper image. Hope this helps! :)